# Spring MVC Form Validation - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, tomcat7, hibernate-validator

I am trying to add form validations to a working application. I started by adding a NotNull check to Login Form. I am using Hibernate impl of Bean Validation api.

Here's the code I have written

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/login")
@Scope("request")
public class LoginController {

  @Autowired
  private CommonService commonService;

  @Autowired
  private SiteUser siteUser;

  @InitBinder
  private void dateBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
      SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
      CustomDateEditor editor = new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true);
      binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, editor);
  }

  @ModelAttribute
  protected ModelMap setupForm(ModelMap modelMap) {
    modelMap.addAttribute("siteUser", siteUser);
    return modelMap;
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView form(ModelMap map){
    if (siteUser.getId() == null){
      map.addAttribute("command",new SiteUser());
      return new ModelAndView("login-form",map);
    }else {
      return new ModelAndView("redirect:/my-dashboard/"+siteUser.getId());
    }
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/submit", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public ModelAndView submit(@Valid SiteUser user, ModelMap map, BindingResult result){
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
      map.addAttribute("command", user);
      System.out.println("Login Error block");
      return new ModelAndView("login/form",map);
    }
    else {
      User loggedInUser = commonService.login(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword());
      if (loggedInUser != null) {
        siteUser.setId(loggedInUser.getId());
        siteUser.setName(loggedInUser.getName());
        System.out.println("site user attr set");
      }
      return new ModelAndView("redirect:/my-dashboard/"+loggedInUser.getId());
    }
  }
}
```

The Model is

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class SiteUser {
private Integer id = null;
@NotNull
private String name = null;
private String email = null;
private String password = null;
private List<String> displayPrivList = null;
private List<String> functionPrivList = null;
    // And the getters and setters
}
```

The JSP is

```
    <c:url var="loginSubmitUrl" value="/login/submit"/>
    <form:form method="POST" action="${loginSubmitUrl}">
        <form:errors path="*" />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span4">
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <h3>Please Login</h3>
                <label><span style="color:red">*</span>Email</Label><form:input path="email" type="text" class="input-medium" />
                <label><span style="color:red">*</span>Password</Label><form:input path="password" type="password" class="input-medium" />
                <br/>       
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </form:form>
```

I have added messages.properties and the annotation driven bean def in the context xml.
Other answers on the subject talk about form fields not getting posted. In my case, that's the expected behavior - that if I submit a blank form, I should get an error.

Please advise what am I missing?

Comment: Posting the log messages would help.. Spring generally reports all these kinds of errors in a very detailed fashion.

Comment: In this case, there is no log message. Even the "Login Error block" sys out is not printed. Interestingly, If I remove the "ModelMap map" parameter from the method signature, the code does enter the error block, but then displays "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute"

Comment: I am not sure of this, but add @ModelAttribute to your command object along with Valid and try

Answer (score 16):

I think this question had the same issue as yours

[Syntactically incorrect request sent upon submitting form with invalid data in Spring MVC (which uses hibernate Validator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336143/syntactically-incorrect-request-sent-upon-submitting-form-with-invalid-data-in-s)

which just points out

> You have to modify the order of your arguments. Put the **BindingResult** result parameter always directly after the parameter with the **@Value** annotation

Comment: +1, trying this method will not hurt and it definitely helped my problem!

Answer (score 1):

You need this: `<form:errors path="email" cssClass="errors" />` 
Use the tag form:errors for each input with the same "path" name.

It is also possible to list all the error at the same time if you don't put a path.

Here, check an full example with sample code that you can download to learn how to do:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the `<form:form>` by including the commandName to it like this

```
     <form:form method="POST" action="${loginSubmitUrl}" commandName="user">
```